# Converting Binding Source to DataTable

Tags: vb.net, winforms

there are soo many examples in c#, but the application is VB. and it seems the equivalent does not want to work for me.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim bsMain As New BindingSource()
bsMain.DataSource = dgvMainLookUp.DataSource
dt = CType(bsMain.DataSource, DataTable)
```

the error is on the last line, and is as follow:

> Unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource to
>   type System.Data.DataTable.

please help me figure out what i am doing wrong. converting DataSource to DataTable should not be so painful

Comment: You can't convert a `BindingSource` to a `DataTable`.  They are two different things.  The error message you're getting indicates that `bsMain` is bound to another `BindingSource` rather than to a `DataTable`.  This has got nothing at all to do with C# and VB and everything to do with how the binding was set up in the first place.  Don't you know how to debug?  Set a breakpoint and look at `bsMain.DataSource` and you should see that it's a `BindingSource`. You can then look at the `DataSource` of that and you'll probably find your `DataTable`.

Comment: If you want top know why a `BindingSource` might be bound to another `BindingSource`, just take a look at [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065) for an example.  By the way, why are you creating a new `DataTable` and then immediately discarding it and using (or trying to use, at least) an existing one?  The `New` keyword creates a new object so don't use it unless you actually want a new object.

Comment: thanks, but i am trying to cast datasource to a datatable, i must have titled my post wrong.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do but you can only cast as type `DataTable` if the object actually is a `DataTable`.  You can't magically turn a `BindingSource` into a `DataTable`.  If you have a `DataTable` that you wanbt to access then you have to access it where it's available, not by magic because you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are setting dgvMainLookUp.DataSource to bsMain or another BindingSource at some point.  In that case, you care trying to cast a BindingSource to a DataTable.  Try something like:

```
Dim bs as BindingSource = dgvMainLookUp.DataSource
Dim dt as DataTable = bs.DataSource
```

You might need a cast but I think it will work as written.

Comment: thanks, but on the first line, i cannot set datasource to type bindinsource. i tried creating a clone of the datasource, but that did not work either :(

Comment: You can set a DataSource = a BindingSource.  That's kind of the whole point of a BindingSource.  Consider the error you are getting.  In order to get this error, bsMain.Datasource has to be a BindingSource.  This indicates that dgvMainLookUp.DataSource has to be a BindingSource.  Try bsMain = dgvMainLookUp.DataSource in your example and see what you get.